# Как правильно написать условие для сравнения строки класса StringBuilder с её реверсом и поместить это в цикл?

Tags: java, строки, циклы

**Суть задачи:** дана строка. Из неё нужно сделать **палиндром** (когда слово читается одинаково и с начала и с конца) минимально возможной длины. Например, есть строка *"abcded"*, из нее должно получится *abcdedcba*.

В целом логика решения понятна, но я не могу её реализовать в коде. Сравниваем строку с её реверсом, если не равно, то добавляем первую букву вконец, на втором проходе вторую букву добавляем на предпоследнее место и т.д.,пока не получится палиндром.

Сначала я пытался решить эту задачу с помощью списков, но слишком громоздко и запутанно, так и не получилось.

Использовав StringBuilder набросал такой код:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abcded");
        sb.insert(sb.length(), sb.charAt(0));
        int count = 1;

       while (sb != sb.reverse()){
           sb.insert(sb.length() - count, sb.charAt(count));
           count++;
       }
        System.out.println(sb);
```

На выходе получаю *"adedcba"*.
Пробовал использовать **if else**, **for**, всё одно и тоже. Пробовал изменить само условие например на `if (str.equals(str.reverse()))`.
Видимо я неправильно пишу условие, да и не совсем понимаю, как работает equals или reverse внутри цикла. Я так понял, что когда делаешь реверс строки даже внутри условия, то строка остается в этом состоянии и нужно её возвращать в исходное положение?
Короче говоря, нужно этот код поместить в цикл, и чтобы всё заработало:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abcded");
        sb.insert(sb.length(),sb.charAt(0));
        sb.insert(sb.length() - 1,sb.charAt(1));
        sb.insert(sb.length() - 2,sb.charAt(2));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что получилось у меня:

```
public class Polindrom {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("abcded");
        strings.add("abcde");
        strings.add("abcd");
        strings.add("abc");
        strings.add("ab");

        for (String string : strings) {
            System.out.println(string + " -> " + makeAPolindrom(string));
        }

    }

    public static String makeAPolindrom(String word) {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(word);

        StringBuilder reversed = new StringBuilder(word).reverse();

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++) {

            if (!word.substring(i).equals(reversed.toString())) {
                result.insert(result.length() - i, word.charAt(i));
                reversed.deleteCharAt(reversed.length() - 1);
            } else if (word.length() - i <= 3) {
                break;
            }

        }

        return result.toString();

    }

}
```

Результат вывода в консоль:

```
abcded -> abcdedcba
abcde -> abcdedcba
abcd -> abcdcba
abc -> abcba
ab -> aba
```

Comment: Tsyklop, спасибо. В iDea всё работает, вывод нормальный. Но на сайте курса, который прохожу, проверяющая система ругается:`Input:
abcb 

Your output:
abcb bcba
Correct output:
abcba`

Comment: @mi6an Проверил в IDEA - Все корректно выводится `abcb -> abcba`. Возможно на сайте курса что-то не так. Скиньте ссылку, на страницу курса.

Comment: @mi6an обратитесь в тех. поддержку сайта. Может прояснят что не так. + выложите код с курса сюда. Я гляну

Comment: ссылка на курс: [https://stepik.org/lesson/90686/step/11?unit=66914] Куратор курса сказала, что на сайте не правильно выводит _"потому что есть пробел в конце. in.nextLine().trim() - уберет лишние пробелы"_